# SSLHandhake failed due to Connection reset while connecting to Websphere MQ with 1 way SSL enabled channel

Tags: java, ssl, ibm-mq

My application is trying to connect to Websphere MQ over a channel which is enabled with 1 way SSL. SSLHandshake is failing due to Connection reset. Below is the snippet of error and the SSL debug logs.

Exception:

```
    Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2397' ('MQRC_JSSE_ERROR')
    Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9204: Connection to host '()' rejected.
    Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9771: SSL handshake failed. [1=java.net.SocketException[Connection reset],3=ip-.ec2.internal/:(ip-.ec2.internal),4=SSLSocket.startHandshake,5=default]
```

SSL Logs:

```
    
    %% No cached client session
    *** ClientHello, TLSv1
    http-nio-8080-exec-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 88
    Session ID:
    {}
    Cipher Suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
    RandomCookie: GMT: 1488604277 bytes = { 111, 107, 58, 215, 226, 30, 121, 44, 107, 106, 206, 48, 72, 149, 173, 69, 156, 158, 199, 199, 201, 23, 106, 150, 24, 193, 1, 95 }
    Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=ip-.ec2.internal]
    Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: 
    ***
    Compression Methods: { 0 }
    http-nio-8080-exec-1, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    http-nio-8080-exec-1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT: fatal, description = unexpected_message
    http-nio-8080-exec-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
    http-nio-8080-exec-1, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    http-nio-8080-exec-1, called closeSocket()
```

I'm not sure whether this is due to protocol or Ciphersuite issue. Kindly suggest.

Comment: you might have to add certificates for this and check proxies

Comment: Server cert has been added to truststore.

Comment: Have you tried the IBM cryptography extension for the jdk/jre? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/de/SSWPVP_2.5.0.3/com.ibm.sklm.doc_2.5.0.3/admin/tsk/tsk_ic_admin_backup_jce_policy_files.html

Comment: Please update your question by clicking edit and add the following details: 1. IBM MQ jar version (use `unzip -p com.ibm.mq.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF|grep -i Implementation-Version` against any of the MQ jars you are using). 2. Queue Manager MQ version.  3. JRE in use, ex: IBM, Oracle, etc. 4. Any corresponding entries from the queue managers AMQERR01.LOG.

Comment: 1. IBM MQ jar version - 8.0.0.7                                          
2.  Queue Manager version - 8.0.0.2.                                 3.  JRE in use - Open JDK.                                                         4. Above are all the logs I could get.

Comment: You may have missed the part where I said "Please update your question by clicking edit and adding the following details:".  I'll make that request again since comments are meant to ask for clarification, etc, but details should go in the question itself.  The queue manager side logs will provide additional assistance in troubleshooting, if you do not have access ask the MQ admin.

Comment: Note that if you want someone to see your comment you put "@username" to tag them.  Can you update your question to provide details of how you are connecting to MQ, what cipher you are specifying.  The logs list `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA`, if this is the case are you specifying `useIBMCipherMappings=false`?  I answered another question from someone using OpenJDK who is having issues as well, can you try this with Oracle or IBM JRE?